# How to launch Activity using intent which passed from Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a `Service` which obtains a class name in a string variable and passes to sharedpreferences using this code:

```
    settings.edit().putString("class", activityClass).commit();
```

`

the service then launches my passprompt activity, which needs to read the String and launch the activity stored inside.

```
     try {

           SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           String c = settings.getString("class", "null");
           Intent newIntent= new Intent(passprompt.this, Class.forName(c));
           newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(newIntent);

        }
       catch  (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       }
```

however the intended activity is not launching when expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this ,

1. If this activity with in your app
   Get the fully qualified Activity class name and put it into intent extra as follows,

   ```
       Intent newIntent= new Intent(Passprompt.this, Class.forName("your activity class name"))); 
       newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(newIntent);
   ```
2. If this is activity within another applicatino

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename", "packagename.launh_activity_name")); 
    startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: thanks David, in the Class.ForName(), intent hasn't been declared which is why I'm having issues, should I make 2 intent objects - one for retreiving  the String and one for launching the new activity?

Comment: What should I use in the parameters of a new intent though? (currentactivity, x activity)

Comment: i have edit the above answer, also its recommended to start class names with a Capital.

Comment: I cannot use your line Intent newIntent = ...etc because the intent object used in Class.forName hasn't been declared. I have edited my original code so you can see how I now have two intent objects declared, however my code now crashes when trying to launch the new activity

Comment: where do you call this method "startActivity(newIntent);"  ? in which activity ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74511/discussion-between-user3343264-and-davidjhons).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74514/discussion-between-davidjhons-and-user3343264).